# Convert DateTime into desired format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-formatting

In my project we are migrating from an Oracle database to SQL Server.

In Oracle, to get the required date format, we will use the `to_char` function - it will return the desired format as we mentioned in the second param:

```
TO_CHAR(TXNDT,'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

In SQL Server, the same thing can be achieved like below.

```
convert(varchar(255), TXNDT, 131)
```

My problem is: I want to get the date format `dd-MM-yyyy hh24:mi:ss`

I can do this in Oracle:

```
TO_CHAR(TXNDT,'dd-MM-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

But how can I achieve the samething in SQL Server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you format the date on your front end application ?

Comment: Yes, I can do it in front end also. It not possible to do format through query like oracle to_char function?

Comment: Yes you can. The fact that doing it in Database end means you are sending string to your front end application rather than datetime

Comment: SQL Server **2012** and newer has a function `FORMAT` to format your dates which ever way you like

Comment: You shouldn't be transferring dates as strings in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format()`.  I think this does what you want:

```
format(TXNDT,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

If you need this as a `varchar()`:

```
convert(varchar(255), format(TXNDT,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: format returns nvarchar. so i cannot fetch though hibernate.its possible to convert nvarchar to varchar

Comment: `FORMAT` is incredibly slow/resource intensive. I suggest against it and stick to `CONVERT`.

Comment: @Larnu . . . There isn't a built-in format that matches what the OP needs.  The overhead on `FORMAT()` in a few queries is probably really minor compared to the effort to move the code.

Comment: @Madhesh: of course it converts that to a string - that's what Oracle's `to_char()` does as well. A `date` has no format at all. If you need to process the actual date value in Java, then select it as a date, not a varchar

Comment: @Gordon, actually the overhead is pretty big for "just a few queries". Using `CONVERT` with other functions (for example `REPLACE`, `STUFF`, `LEFT`, etc) is much faster, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

[CONVERT(Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) has all of the style codes for CONVERT. Note, also, that you need to CONVERT to a `varchar`, not a `datetime`. datetime has a fixed display format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss.

So, for you, it would be `CONVERT(varchar(20),TXNDT,120)`. notice the use of varchar, rather than datetime.

Comment: we are supporting various date format separators so have to pass the format string in the function